# add child entity with correct managed object context

Tags: ios, core-data, one-to-many

I create new child entity in detailed view controller. So I send in segue

```
detailedViewController.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;
detaledViewController.parent = currentParent; //type of Parent
```

At detailViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)saveChildObj:(id)sender{
  self.childEntity= [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ChildEntity" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        self.childEntity.childEntityName= self.childEntityName.text;

        [self.parent addMyChildObject:self.childEntity];
        [self.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
            NSError *error = nil;
            BOOL saved = [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
            if (!saved) {
                // do some real error handling
                NSLog(@"Could not save Date due to %@", error);
            }
            [[osCoreDataController sharedImstanse] saveMasterContext];
        }];


        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

After calling addMyChildEntity I have error with text:

```
2013-06-09 22:21:39.191 FindYourMedicine[2476:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'parent' between objects in different contexts (source = <ChildEntity: 0x8acbf30> (entity: ChildEntity; id: 0x8accb10 <x-coredata:///ChildEntity/t8DB5D204-A359-45E5-8F2B-8DE6A26D245C3> ; data: {
    date =     (
    );
    parent= nil;
    childEntityName= fgh;
    times =     (
    );
}) , destination = <Parent: 0x8a9a9a0> (entity: Parent; id: 0x8a99cb0 <x-coredata://48BBE637-9D07-4529-9C6A-DCCF118B4717/Disease/p2> ; data: {
    parentName = "\U0430\U0441\U0442\U043c\U0430";
    childEntity=  (
```

);

The structure of core data is to many:  **Parent ->>Child ->> Times**

I tried to use managedObjectContext.parantContext but nothing help

Comment: I solved it! Problem was with sending wrong context.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the managed object context, just pass the parent. Then, when you need to add the child just ask the parent for its managed object context (all managed objects have this property).